# Load/Recompile Rebar Modules after downgrading Erlang/OTP

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I wish to use an erlang client library to communicate with an mqtt broker for one of my projects. So I've started an application using rebar3's built-in templates and added emqttc as a dependency. Since [erlang/otp 21 does not have support for gen_logger](https://github.com/emqtt/gen_logger/issues/5)(emqttc depends on gen_logger) and the `tuple_calls` compiler options do not suffice, I had to downgrade to erlang@20 according to [this post](https://github.com/emqtt/emqtt_benchmark/issues/36).

Now the issue with downgrading erlang is that, none of rebar3's commands(clean/compile/shell/report etc) work as expected and my previous projects built with rebar3 do not compile, I get to see this error message:

> =ERROR REPORT==== 21-Aug-2018::12:54:29 === Loading of /usr/local/bin/rebar3/rebar/ebin/rebar3.beam failed: badfile escript:
>   exception error: undefined function rebar3:main/1   in function 
>   escript:run/2 (escript.erl, line 759)   in call from escript:start/1
>   (escript.erl, line 277)   in call from init:start_em/1   in call from
>   init:do_boot/3
>
> =ERROR REPORT==== 21-Aug-2018::12:54:29 === beam/beam_load.c(1863): Error loading module rebar3:   This BEAM file was compiled for a later
>   version of the run-time system than 20.   To fix this, please
>   recompile this module with an 20 compiler.   (Use of opcode 160; this
>   emulator supports only up to 159.)

I've uninstalled and reinstalled rebar3, looked up on the web for this but nothing's clear and specific to rebar. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you install rebar from?

Comment: @legoscia from Homebrew

Comment: I uninstalled erlang20 and rebar3 from my macOS high sierra and reinstalled them via homebrew, only to realize that homebrew considers erlang21 as a rebar3 dependency and pours in erlang21 formula before pouring rebar3. And I ran into the same error of rebar modules not loading/compiling again.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the exact answer for your question. But it may give you and idea.

What about using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). Its an easy way to keep your environment clean and neat.

If you use docker, you just have to include your new erlang version in `Dockerfile` as an environment variable.

`ENV OTP_VERSION="20.3.6"`

Answer (score 1):

Check your  ***_build/prod/rel/YOURAPPNAME***/ directory. Most probably it has a release which doesn't match your erlang version. You can safely delete this directory and rebuild using rebar3 compile